# Multiple Wordpress Websites, one Database, but different content,options,themes

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

i have some newly hosted 3-4 shared  websites

Is there any provision of setting up multiple wordpress websites with different themes,content,images,plugins etc

In each websites has its separate themes,plugins and separate content and it will be hosted on separate domains

i want the admin to access backend of all the websites from one wordpress admin panel

**overall i'm trying to say is one to many concept means one admin panel for different website**

Is there any chance to do like that

If not Please suggest me some good solution

Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress administration


Comment: Yes , you can use Wordpress network (http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)  for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after running a quick Google Search I found this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-enable-multi-site-option-in-wordpress-3-0/
http://infinitewp.com/

But I don't believe from the fact someone has already insulted your post this is the right place to ask

Comment: and Bhumi Shah - Thnx for u r replies will definetly workout on it and wat are the keywords you have searched in google for results

#Mike : sorry i'm nt a regular user of stackoverflow so i dont knw the rules and regulations can u please send me a link regarding about the rules and regulations of website

Comment: @SaideepKankarla if you find my answer helpful please mark it as an answer, secondly simply type `manage multiple wordpress sites from one dashboard`